# Node.JS images not displaying to clients

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have server.js and client.html.
Server.js is running on nodejs and is simply:

```
var http = require('http'), fs = require('fs');

var app = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    fs.readFile("client.html", 'utf-8', function(error, data) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write(data);
    response.end();     
    });
}).listen(80);
```

and then I have client.html which is also very simply just

```
<img src="/public/images/avatar.gif">
```

Which just displays as though the image is not valid, I have checked the the director over and over and it is fine, why would it be doing this? I thought it might be because of the headers but text/html should surely display images?

Regards

Matt

Comment: You aren't serving the public directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not displaying the image because for every request (including the image request) it's returning the contents of clients.html.

If you want a static file server, i suggest looking at connect: http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/ or for something simpler, have a look at this: https://gist.github.com/rpflorence/701407

Comment: But the contents of clients.html is <img src="/public/images/avatar.gif"> so why would it not be able to source the image?

Comment: That image tag will send a request to localhost/public/images/avatar.gif and your node.js code will handle that request by sending back the contents of client.html. Your node.js code will do that for ALL requests.